# laying out a large graph with graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

My daughters have made a game not unlike tic-tac-toe.  Of course as I played it with them I started brute-forcing it in my head...

So at lunchtime I made a quick little Python script to 'solve' the game.  And I wanted to see the results graphically, so I generated a dot file of all legal moves:

[I've pasted the data here](https://gist.github.com/4087256).

When I try and render it using `dot`, it takes forever and I abort it after a few hours.

If I render it using `neato` or `sfdp` etc, it takes a few seconds or less but the layout is impossible to actually read:

```
sfdp -x -Tpng data.dot > data.png
```

[image: sfdp]

```
neato -x -Tpng data.dot > data.png
```

[image: neato]

I would be happy for the resulting image to be several megapixels.

How can I lay out and render such a big graph?  I am open to non-dot suggestions, like Python libraries that can do the layout too.

<sup>([somewhat related link](http://xkcd.com/832/))</sup>

*Added*: [my Python script](https://gist.github.com/4087469) to solve the game and generate the dot file

Comment: How many nodes/edges are there in the graph? You might try http://gephi.org/

Comment: @gephi.org there are 744 nodes and 4361 edges.  A dot that I left running has just seg-faulted on this dot-file.

Comment: @Will Can you give some sort of intuition about execution time for this dataset?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
sfdp -x -Goverlap=scale -Tpng data.dot > data.png
```

The `-Goverlap` preserves the layout but uniformly scales things up until there are no more node overlaps. I was able to get a ~77MB PNG that looks like this when you zoom out.
[image]

Comment: This looks very promising; despite having 4GB of RAM, I hit swap as soon as I try and view the generated image, though :(  Any tips on how to view and resize such large images?

Comment: @will I was able to open it in GIMP, but it was slow. You can run `dot -Txxx` to get a list of other output formats available. I was also able to specify `-Tx11` to bring up an interactive display of the layout (scroll wheel to zoom, middle-mouse drag to pan around).

Comment: yeah I couldn't get anything to view it, and back-of-an-envelope I ought to have the RAM even at 16bit RGB canvases.  I looked briefly at `nip2` too, but couldn't actually work out how to save a file.. I just admitted defeat, blogged about it and moved on!  Thx http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/35858593837/tic-tac-toe

Comment: I've seen a few implementations of viewing interfaces for giant images that use similar techniques to Google maps, @Will. Have you tried any of those? After a quick look, I found [GSV](http://mike.teczno.com/giant/pan/) with source code, and a zoomable version of that giant [xkcd comic](http://xkcd-map.rent-a-geek.de/). The GSV page had some code for splitting the image into tiles.

Comment: How can you make it hierarchical view instead of circular?

Comment: Are you able to give some information on how long this took to generate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any static format was too heavy in my case. The only way I managed to visualize it was to generate an xdot as output and then use this: https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py
And you can use the command-line as follows so the visualizer respects the layout information embedded into the xdot file: xdot --no-filter output.xdot

Comment: `gdal2tiles.py --processes=8 -p raster data.png`; then you can open the generated directory, run `python3 -m http.server` and open http://0.0.0.0:8000/openlayers.html

Answer (score 10):

you could still use the neato but modify the .dot file putting: [splines=true overlap=false]

And your file should look like this:

```
digraph luffarschack {
    graph [splines=true overlap=false];
    node [shape=none]; 
        ...here your nodes;
        ...here your edges;
}
```

It should work if you just put in the second line "graph [splines=true overlap=false]" and everything else remains the same.

Comment: Early on it printed out "Warning: some nodes with margin (3.20,3.20) touch - falling back to straight line edges", and then after 13 minutes OSX pops up the "force quit" dialog because my system had run out of its 16GB of RAM!  I'd love to see the layout this produces if you can manage to run it?

Comment: Done and done...just give me an email adress and I will send you the .svg file (4 MB)...I can't find the upload option in here

Comment: there's an email address on my profile page; much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry thought it was publicly visible (varfar at yahoo co uk)

Comment: This helped me but I left out `splines=true` because it was really slow.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to other answers, you may use other tools like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/).

> Gephi is the leading visualization and exploration software for all kinds of graphs and networks. Gephi is open-source and free.

Runs on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I found dot with the default `-Kneato` too slow on my large graph ([svg](http://jnnnnn.github.io/needs/feelings.svg)). I ended up using

```
dot -Ksfdp -ooutput.svg -Tsvg input.dot
```

where `input.dot` was

```
digraph {
    graph [overlap=false];
    a -> {b c d e f g}
    b -> {c e g x f}
    ...
}
```