# Graphviz is too slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

I am trying to generate a graph that has 100 nodes and 4000 edges, and it has been over 10 minutes. I am using the [python graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) code. Below is the function used to generate the graph.

```py
    def draw_graph(self):
        dot = Digraph(format="png")#comment="This assignment sucks")
        edges = set()
        for k, v in self.graph.items():
            dot.node(self.letter(k))
            for neighbor in v:
                edge = self.letter(k) + "_" + self.letter(neighbor)
                if edge not in edges:
                    edges.add(edge)
#        dot.edges(list(edges))
        for edge in edges:
            dot.edge(*edge.split("_"))
        dot.render('og.gv', view=True)
```

The `self.graph` is a dictionary where the keys are nodes and the values are the adjacent nodes.

After doing some googling, I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18831091/8903959 but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make these changes in Python3. Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed up graph generation? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: 2 thoughts: you are averaging 80 edges per node - that is a lot. Secondly, I don't use the Python interface, but you might try output format="canon" and then use that as input into dot (or neato or fdp)

Comment: There was indeed too many edges per node, but I'm still curious how you could optimize this using the nslimit arguments

Comment: Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238724/visualizing-undirected-graph-thats-too-large-for-graphviz#answer-26245864). Using [graph_tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de) python library, a graph with 1490 nodes and 19090 edges was rendered in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the answer to the link you provided, it lists the attributes: [`nslimit`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nslimit/), [`nslimit1`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nslimit1/), [`mclimit`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/mclimit/) for `dot` [layout engine](https://graphviz.org/docs/layouts/), and [`maxiter`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/maxiter/) for `neato` or `fdp` layout engines; and attribute [`splines`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/).

By default your code uses `dot` layout engine as described in [documentation](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#basic-usage). If the choice of engine is not important to you, then for example `neato` gives almost 10 times acceleration (according to my observations), to use it (or to use the other engines such as `circo` or `twopi`, that are listed in the link that you pointed out in your question) you can see an [example in the documentation](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#engines):

```py
import graphviz  
g = graphviz.Graph(engine='neato')
# You can also change engine attribute on existing instance:
g.engine = 'circo'
```

To use the attributes `nslimit`, `nslimit1` and etc, in your code, you can look in the [GraphViz documentation](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nslimit/) to which object (Graph, Node or Edge) the attribute belongs (for example about `nslimit`, cite: *Valid on: Graphs*) and write it in your code according to the [python graphviz library's documentation](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#styling):

```py
import graphviz  
ps = graphviz.Digraph('pet-shop',
                      graph_attr={'nslimit': '0',
                                  'nslimit1': '2'},
                      node_attr={'shape': 'plaintext'},
                      edge_attr={'color': 'black'})
```

For example, I will replace the line `dot = Digraph(format="png")` with:

```py
dot = Digraph(format="png",
              engine='neato', # Layout engine.
              graph_attr=dict(splines='true',
                              sep='5',
                              overlap='scale'),
              node_attr=dict(shape='circle',   
                             margin='0',
                             fontsize='10',
                             width='0.2',
                             height='0.2',
                             fixedsize='true'),
              edge_attr=dict(arrowsize='0.4'))
```

and get result (34 seconds, 55 MB, posted a thumbnail):
[image: graph made with python graphviz]

I recreated [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your example for testing:

```py
from graphviz import Digraph
import random

nodes = 100 # 50 can be used for test purposes, to reduce time.
outgoing_edges = 40 # Because 40 edges * 100 nodes = 4000 edges

class G:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = {}
        # Fill graph with randomly generated data:
        for node in range(nodes):
            self.graph[node] = random.sample(range(nodes), outgoing_edges)

    def letter(self, key):
        return str(key)

    def draw_graph(self):
        dot = Digraph(format="png")
        edges = set()
        for k, v in self.graph.items():
            dot.node(self.letter(k))
            for neighbor in v:
                edge = self.letter(k) + "_" + self.letter(neighbor)
                if edge not in edges:
                    edges.add(edge)
    #   dot.edges(list(edges))
        for edge in edges:
            dot.edge(*edge.split("_"))
        dot.render('og.gv', view=True)

g = G()
g.draw_graph()
```

You can measure the speed of `dot.render()` with `timeit`:

```py
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
func1()
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```